# Canon LBP5050 recognized but doesn't print

Tags: usb, printing, canon

I tried many different ways to get my printer to work:

- I tried using a generic Model for the printer, since it is not supported by ubuntu yet.
- I tried using a model that is close to the one I have.
- I tried downloading the official .rpm package and repack it as a .deb package and install it (Not sure if that actually worked).
- I tried to run the script provided [here](http://radu.cotescu.com/how-to-install-canon-lbp-printers-in-ubuntu/) and that [seems to have worked for others](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1315665) but not for me.

What I have now is this:
My printer is recognized with the right name, Make and Model. When I send data to the printer it changes from 'Idle' to 'Processing' and then just flags the job as done, even though it didn't do a thing.

I have no idea how to repair the mess I created. If anyone has an idea, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I have had exactly the same problems as you describe (on a 64-bit Ubuntu) but with the LBP7200Cdn printer.
Today I (coincidentally) found a new(er) version of the Canon CAPT drivers (2.56), including a precompiled 64-bit debian archive [here](http://support-au.canon.com.au/contents/AU/EN/0100459602.html).

After trying this version, with exactly the same [(official Ubuntu) steps](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190) as I tried many times before, it worked instantly!
So maybe this will solve your (similar) problems as well!